# Cannot open database <db_name> requested by the login.The login failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I know this might be a duplicate questions but I checked all the answers provided and none of them worked for me.

My applications (both winform and asp.net) were working fine with the way I worked with them but now all of a sudden none of them will connect to the local sqlserver database.

I am using this connection string (both hard coded or using the web.config in asp.net applications) :

`Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=<my_db_name>;Integrated Security=True;`

but now I get this `SqlException` since this morning:

`Cannot open database <my_db_name> requested by the login. The login failed.Login failed for user '<my_computer's_username\my_computer's_username-pc'>.`

again I know this been asked a lot of times but almost none of the answers were for a `ConnectionString` with `integrated security = true` and for the few ones that were, the answers didn't work for me.

ps1:right now there's a login under username `dbo` with `<my_computer's_username\my_computer's_username-pc'>` as its login in my database

ps2:I can successfully login to my database with windows security option in sqlserver managment studio 2014

Comment: But I used this in the past for my webites. what about winforms applications that are not working either??

Comment: Ah, perhaps it can be done. https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/allowing-iis-7-5-applications-to-communicate-to-sql-server-via-windows-authentication/   Every place I have been at always said it didn't work. Hope that link helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These problems can be difficult to solve, precisely because SQL Server has rejected the login attempt for its own security.

You say you can log in to the database. Is the application running as you, or another user? Your PS1 is not relevant for Windows Authentication.

Check that you have enabled Windows Authentication mode (which is what `Integrated Security = True` means) in the instance. Start SSMS and right-click on the instance (not the database) in the Object Explorer and select Properties. Select the Security page. Ensure that Windows Authentication mode is selected.

Check your connection string. There is lots of information on http://www.connectionstrings.com/. 
You may need to name your instance `Data Source=.\ServerName;` or try `Integrated Security=SSPI;`

Comment: answering to your questionThe other applications that I created and worked before were all in this system, with the same os, with the same config as before

Comment: The question was meant to ask 'Who runs the application?' Is it you or another user? If you can sign on in SSMS but cannot run the application, it looks like a connection string problem. If another Windows user cannot run the application, it looks like a SQL Server security problem.

Comment: the server authentication is in `windows authentication mode` and I can indeed login to the server using SSMS with windows mode authentication.
As your comment suggests it should be a connection string problem but what is wrong with it?

Comment: you were absolutely right!!!!
In my connection string, I misspelled the database(catalog) name and now it is working. Thanks for the advice